# Is C-3PO able to learn new languages?

Tags: star-wars

Sure, he (it) is fluent in over 6 million forms of communication. But the Ewoks were on a primitive moon. They clearly were removed from the galactic scene until the Empire began construction on the second Death Star.

So is C-3PO like a universal translator (from *Star Trek*) which can extrapolate languages based on context? Is he adaptive? Or is it just a miracle that once upon a time someone did a language analysis on the Ewoks and then Anakin decided to include it in his memory banks.

Comment: He gets regular updates on the first Tuesday of each month via the Droid Update system.  From time to time, they will release in between Hotfix updates, further information which is available via article kb33422412212.  Every year or two they will release a rolled up Service Pack update including all patches to that point.  Should a patch fail, you can reboot and select "Last Known Good Configuration" in order to roll back his OS to the last restore point.

Comment: Actually, it's an OTA update. And since C3PO is on AT&T, he never gets them.

Comment: @DVK - That's why my Droids always run off of the Verizon Alliance Network.  You can't trust any company whose logo looks like the Death Star.

Comment: 0101011001100001011100000110111101110010011000010111010001101111011100100111001100111111

Comment: [DeusExMachina](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeusExMachina)

Comment: ... darn, I tvtroped myself ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, He did it with the Ewoks.

> They're using a very primitive dialect. But I do believe they think I am some sort of god.

[Ewokese](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewokese), was a dialect derivative from Yuzzum language, which was know by C3PO. He had to extrapolate from it to communicate with Ewoks.

Also, according to [is Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PO#Yuuzhan_Vong_War_and_the_Dark_Nest_Crisis_.2825_ABY.E2.80.9336_ABY.29), he was able to learn [Yuuzhan Vong language](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong_language)

> He was the one who was able to translate the Yuuzhan Vong language which benefited the New Republic greatly.

Comment: Speaking to the Ewoks was an example, but is he able to quickly learn new languages which have no basis on existing ones?

Comment: @JackBNimble updated

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, C3PO is able to learn new languages. He would be less than effective if he couldn't, seeing that languages are not static and constantly evolving. He is similar to the Universal translator from Star Trek, but appears to be less sophisticated, in some respects and more sophisticated in others. Given the number of alien species in Imperial Space, a capacity for learning new languages seems almost like a requirement.**

He has shown several instances of being able to parse a less well known language (interacting with the Ewoks) and even languages from species previously unknown to the Empire. It makes sense he should be able to adapt his experience with previous languages to quickly and effectively create a database of interactions even when exposed to a new language.

### How he learns new languages

To learn a new language C3PO would have to create correspondences between existing languages and that would take time. More likely, when confronted with new languages:

- He firsts checks to see if, after taking a sample, there were other languages with similar structures, syntax, or style relationships,
- He gathers and compare all such subjects for the closest matches;
- Only after finding there were few or no relationships would he begin the hardest task of compiling a database based on direct communication, (slowest method possible)
- This would require interacting, memorizing words, structures and relationships (which could all be extrapolated from previous experiences) and aid in learning of the new language.
- Unlike an organic, he would have the ability to reference every type of language he knows to speed his ability to relate to the new language, vocabulary being the most difficult to acquire since it would be completely new (if there was no parent language to compare it to).
- The number of languages he speaks also does not take into account whether each listed language, includes region or localized variants which may take place as languages stay separated. His actual number of languages could be significantly higher.

### His language advantages and limitations

While C3PO is conversant in six million forms of communication, he is limited to sonic forms of communication. Any languages that could have visual or movement based-components, which considering his movement limitations, would not be easy to perform or based in scent, color, or emitted light (perhaps his eyes could assist there) he would be less effective.

With all the diversity of life in the galaxy, C3PO seems best suited to communicate with lifeforms that use sound as their primary communication medium. We are forced to assume he can also reach infrasonic and ultrasonic ranges as well. This would widen his communication range significantly.

### A sample of language development

The challenge and necessity for a protocol droid, like C3PO in the Imperial Galaxy can be seen from the language development on Earth for example. Consider that Earth may have, depending on who you ask, six to ten thousand languages, the Imperial Galaxy is more homogenized or his adaptive matrix is quickly able to deal with regionalization of languages as they split off from their parent languages. Consider the two major language structures of Earth and how their languages relate. (see Proto-Indo-European and Sino Tibetian Language trees, below)

Depending on the number of planets in the galaxy, and their relationships and species, he would have to keep a number of data trees for every major working group in the galaxy he is familiar with. Each of those sub-trees is a distinct language. This also implies there is a possibility of a data/language upgrade system allowing protocol droids to share information from distant systems as languages change and evolve.

[image: Proto-Indo-European Language Tree]

[image: Sino-Tibetian Language Tree]

**Further Reference:**

- [How Many Languages in the World](http://www.danielburke.com/files/howmany.pdf): A simple overview defining the challenge of determining how to count the number of languages on Earth.
- [Languages of the World](http://www.ling.gu.se/projekt/sprakfrageladan/english/sprakfakta/eng-sprak-i-varlden.html): An old reference talking about language distribution on Earth.

Comment: This answer, like a number of your answers, is well written, but doesn't seem to do much to address the actual question that has been asked, other than one paragraph. Is there any way you could reduce the signal to noise ratio in your future answers?

Answer (score 1):

Using the term "learn" liberally here the answer is...

#### Yes

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens - The Visual Dictionary* it shows us that C-3PO has upgraded his TranLang III communications package to learn more languages.

> [image: Star Wars: The Force Awakens - The Visual Dictionary, C-3PO's Data File]
>
> C-3PO has upgraded his TranLag III communications package to increase his language fluency to over seven million forms of communication.